# What is this constructor expecting?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working with a API in VB.NET and I have an object constructor that is:

```
CustomObject(pOtherObject As OtherObject*)
```

Is the * a dereference operator in .NET? Based on the "p" in the pOtherObject I am guessing they are expecting a pointer.... My understanding of .Net is the closest thing available to a pointer is a `IntPtr`

Sorry, I know this is not a lot to work with.

Comment: Is this really the constructor of your class? I'd expect it to look like     `Public Sub New(pOtherObject As OtherObject*) ...  End Sub`

Comment: This is what is showing up in the intellisense when I go to new CustomObject. This is not my class, I am trying to use the API (which does not have good documentation). I have never seen * operator next to a object type in vb/c#.net....

Comment: please tag this as C# or VB, but not both.

Comment: It might also be helpful to know what API you are operating against.

Comment: Looks like it comes from C++. Try pass any OtherObject instance to the method. Do you have any compilation errors? If so, what's their text?

Comment: @SamAxe It is not publicly available. Unfortunately I have made the question as generic as possible.

Comment: Unmanaged pointer types are not CLS compliant for exactly this reason. Some languages, such as VB.NET, do not support them.

Comment: You can use Pointers in .net. To be more specific: in c# and there also only in an unsafe context. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx
But for vb.net I don't see this happening

Comment: Looks like Ruby... Nope it's C++ a pointer.